# d3js,vuejs, select a subtree

Tags: d3.js, vue.js, subtree

i am a beginner in the JS, Vue and D3 programming but already managed to understand the basics, i think :).
So currently i am trying to implement a program which renders a phylogenetical tree using Vue.js and D3.js. Using this example as a start up:
https://bl.ocks.org/lorenzopub/02ccce43d708919ca7c0b242fe1c93f2

So far i managed to get my program to open a tree file and to render it properly. Also i can select certain nodes and change their color accordingly. But my problem now is how to select a subtree and change the color of the children nodes.

Any help and or hints will be appreciated!
Thank you!

Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="VUE/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="D3/d3.js"></script>
<script>function parseNewick(s) {
    var ancestors = [];
    var tree = {};
    var tokens = s.split(/\s*(;|\(|\)|,|:)\s*/);
    for (var i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
      var token = tokens[i];
      switch (token) {
        case '(': // new branchset
          var subtree = {};
          tree.branchset = [subtree];
          ancestors.push(tree);
          tree = subtree;
          break;
        case ',': // another branch
          var subtree = {};
          ancestors[ancestors.length-1].branchset.push(subtree);
          tree = subtree;
          break;
        case ')': // optional name next
          tree = ancestors.pop();
          break;
        case ':': // optional length next
          break;
        default:
          var x = tokens[i-1];
          if (x == ')' || x == '(' || x == ',') {
            tree.name = token;
          } else if (x == ':') {
            tree.length = parseFloat(token);
          }
      }
    }
    return tree;
  };
</script>
<style>
.node {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .node circle {
      fill: #999;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node--internal circle {
      fill: #555;
    }
    .node--leaf circle {
      fill: blue;
    }

    .node--selected circle {
    fill: blue
    }
    .node--internal text {
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #555;
      stroke-opacity: 0.4;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
      stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    }

    .node:hover {
      pointer-events: all;
      stroke: #ff0000;
    }

    .node.highlight {
      fill: red;
    }

    .controls {
      position: fixed;
      top: 16px; 
      left: 16px;
      background: #f8f8f8;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .controls > * + * {
      margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    label {
      display: block;
    }

    .list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
      transition: all 1s;
    }
    .list-enter, .list-leave-to /* .list-leave-active for <2.1.8 */ {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(30px);
    }

    .line-enter-active, .line-leave-active {
      transition: all 2s;
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    .line-enter, .line-leave-to /* .list-leave-active for <2.1.8 */ {
      stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    }  

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="app">
    <div class='controls'>
        <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
        <label>Search...</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="search" />
    </div>
    <svg v-bind:width="settings.width" v-bind:height="settings.height">
            <!-- LINKS BETWEEN NODES -->
        <transition-group tag="g" name="line">
            <g v-for="link in links" v-bind:key="link.id">
            <path class="link" v-bind:style="link.style" v-bind:d="link.d"></path>
            </g>
        </transition-group>

            <!-- LINKS BETWEEN NODES -->
        <transition-group tag="g" name="list">
            <g class="node" v-on:dblclick="selectSubTree(node,index)" v-on:mouseover="mouseOver(node,index)" v-on:click="select(node,index)" v-for="(node, index) in nodes" v-bind:key="node.id" v-bind:style="node.style" v-bind:class="[node.className, {'highlight': node.highlight}]">

                <!-- Circles for each node -->  

                <circle v-bind:r="node.r" v-bind:style="node.selCol"></circle>

                <!-- Finally, text labels -->

                <text v-bind:dx="node.textpos.x" v-bind:dy="node.textpos.y" v-bind:style="node.textStyle">{{ node.text }}</text>

            </g>
        </transition-group>         

    </svg>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function (){
      return {
            treeFile: '',
            search: '',
            selected: [],
            settings: {
              strokeColor: "#19B5FF",
              width: 1000,
              height: 1000
            }
      }

  },
  computed: {
    root: function(){
        var vm = this;

        if(vm.treeFile){
            return vm.tree(
            d3.hierarchy(parseNewick(vm.treeFile),function(d) { return d.branchset; })
            .sum(function(d) { return d.branchset ? 0 : 1; })
            .sort(function(a, b) { return (a.value - b.value) || d3.ascending(a.data.length, b.data.length); }));

        }
    },
    tree: function(){
        return d3.tree().size([this.settings.height, this.settings.width - 160]);
    },
    nodes: function(){
        var vm = this;
        if(this.root){
            return vm.root.descendants().map(function(d,i) {
                vm.selected[i]=0;
                return{ 
                    id: d.data.name,
                    index: i,
                    r: 7,
                    className: "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"),
                    text: d.data.name.substring(d.data.name.lastIndexOf(".") +1),
                    highlight: d.data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(vm.search.toLowerCase()) != -1 && vm.search != "",
                    style: {
                        transform: "translate(" + d.y + "px," + d.x + "px)",
                    },
                    textpos: {
                        x: d.children ? -10 : 10,
                        y: 3
                    },
                    textStyle: {
                        textAnchor: d.children ? "end" : "start"
                    },
                    children: d.children,
                    selCol: {fill: '#bfbfbf'}
                };
            });
        }
    },
    links: function() {
        var vm = this;

        if (vm.root) {
          // here we'll calculate the "d" attribute for each path that is then used in the template where we use "v-for" to loop through all of the links to create <path> elements
            return vm.root.descendants().slice(1).map(function(d) {
                return {
                    id: d.data.name,
                    d: "M" + d.y + "," + d.x + "C" + (d.parent.y + 100) + "," + d.x + " " + (d.parent.y + 100) + "," + d.parent.x + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x,

              // here we could of course calculate colors depending on data but for now all links share the same color from the settings object that we can manipulate using UI controls and v-model

                    style: {
                        stroke: vm.settings.strokeColor
                    }
                };
            });
        }
    }       
    },
  methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var vm = this;

      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        vm.treeFile = e.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    },
    select: function(node, index) {
        var vm = this;
    if(this.selected[index] == 0){
        this.selected[index]=1;
        vm.nodes[index].selCol='fill: green';
    }else{
        this.selected[index]=0;
        vm.nodes[index].selCol='fill: #bfbfbf';
    }
    vm.$forceUpdate();
      },
    mouseOver: function (node,index){
//      console.log(node.id + " " + node.isSelected);
    },
    selectSubTree: function(node,index){
        var vm=this;
        if(this.selected[index] == 0){
        this.selected[index]=1;
        vm.nodes[index].selCol='fill: green';
        }else{
        this.selected[index]=0;
        vm.nodes[index].selCol='fill: #bfbfbf';
        }
        if(node.children){
//          console.log(node.id + " HAVE CHILDREN");
//          console.log("NC: " + node.children);
            node.children.forEach(function (d,i){
//              this.selected=i;
                vm.selected[i]=1;
                vm.nodes[index].selCol='fill: green';
                console.log("SELECTING: " + d.data.name + " " + i);
                console.log(vm.$refs.A);
//              if(d.isSelected){
//                  this.selected=i;
//                  console.log("CS :" + this.selected);
//              }
            });
        }else{
//          console.log(node.id + " DONT HAVE CHILDREN");
        }
        vm.$forceUpdate();
    }
  }
})
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: That's far too much code to comprehend. Can you narrow down the problem you're having an make it clear what you have tried, what you expect to happen and what actually happens

Comment: The problem i hit on is that i am not sure how to change the color of the children.I use the method selectSubTree to do that. In it i can change the color of the parent node using its index as all nodes have indices. Say i have a graph with nodes A,B,C,D,E,F, they have indices 0 to 5. Nodes C and D are children of B but those have indices starting from zero as well: 0 and 1. So when i loop through the children i see only 0 and 1 for the children and not 2 and 3. But if i could access the major indices(2,3) of C and D i could change their color easily.I am sorry for the complicated explanation.